# how to iterate over a m2m field with __contains

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to search within 3 manytomany fields within a model to see if a user is within either of those fields. I'm using Q for an or on all 3 fields but I can't seem to find a way to actually see the results.

```
raid_teams = Team.objects.filter(Q(tanks__contains=profile.pk) or Q(healers__contains=profile.pk) or Q(dps__contains=profile.pk))
```

I'm probably going about this completely the wrong way. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__contains is used for case-sensitive containment search (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains), you just need plain id equality match:

```
raid_teams = Team.objects.filter(
    Q(tanks__id=profile.pk) |
    Q(healers__id=profile.pk) | 
    Q(dps__id=profile.pk)
)
```